# Signed apk with ProGuard enabled getting crash

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, android-livedata

I created an open class for receiving data:

```
open class Event<out T>(private val content: T) {

var hasBeenHandled = false
    private set // Allow external read but not write

/**
 * Returns the content and prevents its use again.
 */
fun getContentIfNotHandledOrReturnNull(): T? {
    return if (hasBeenHandled) {
        null
    } else {
        hasBeenHandled = true
        content
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the content, even if it's already been handled.
 */
fun peekContent(): T = content
```

}

But in Signed apk getting error in this import

My Proguard

```
 -ignorewarnings
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
-keep public class com.vslib.base.model.Job { *; }
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.*{ public *; }
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
}
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.provider.Settings
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,EnclosingMethod
-keep class * extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel {
    <init>();
}
-keep class * extends androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel {
    <init>(android.app.Application);
}
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepclassmembers enum androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Event {
    <fields>;
}
-keep class androidx.lifecycle.* { *; }

Error LOG:

 

at com.packagename.fragment.a(SourceFile:32)
        at g.j.a.c.j.i.j.a(SourceFile:7)
        at g.j.a.c.h.i.e.onTransact(SourceFile:3)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:504)
        at dx.aZ(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@210915051@21.09.15 (040408-0):2)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bj.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@210915051@21.09.15 (040408-0):1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
```

Getting the above error while using the event class . If i hide the class it was working fine but if enable getting crash. Can any one help out on this. Need with proguard enable also

Comment: at least post your crash log and proguard config

Comment: @bbsimon pls can you look on this